# Problema al enviar datos del DataGridView del formulario hijo al formulario padre. No ocurre nada

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Necesito enviar un renglón de un datagrid view de un formulario hijo a los text box de un formulario padre. Luego de enviarlos el formulario hijo debe cerrarse en automático.

tengo un formulario hijo al cual mando llamar desde un formulario padre con el siguiente código:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
Button1.Click
Dim S As New SelUN 
    S.MdiParent = Me.ParentForm
    consultar(S.DataGridView1)
    S.Show()
    S.DataGridView1.Columns(0).HeaderText = "Código"
    S.DataGridView1.Columns(0).Visible = False
    S.DataGridView1.Columns(1).HeaderText = "Nombre"
    S.DataGridView1.Columns(1).Width = 438
 End Sub
```

Hasta aquí todo marcha bien y el formulario hijo se muestra sin problema, además el formulario padre se queda abierto mientras se abre el formulario hijo, que es como lo ocupo.

En el formulario hijo, tengo un DataGridView, al cual requiero pasarle las columnas de un renglón a los TextBox del formulario Padre. Lo hago con este código:

```
Sub mostrar_datos()
    Try
        With DataGridView1

            AddCTA.TextBox1.Text = .Item(0, .CurrentRow.Index).Value   
            AddCTA.TextBox2.Text = .Item(1, .CurrentRow.Index).Value
        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

Luego en el DataGrid, mando llamar la función anterior con este código.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
    mostrar_datos()
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Pero no ocurre nada, los datos no se pasan al formulario padre, ni el formulario hijo se cierra. No me manda ningún error de ejecución el código.

Comment: Podrías verificar si te esta dando algún error la consola

Comment: Hola Raul, no, no me da ningún error.